# How to append a variable to a object in php

Tags: php, variables, append

I have this, that doesnt work obviously.

```
$start = $hours->start{$day};
```

I need to be able the change the $day dynamically. $day can be any day of the week

```
//For example
$start = $hours->startSunday;
```

Let me try to be more clear. The following objects contain a certain time

```
// will echo something like 8:00am
echo $hours->startSunday;

//will echo something like 7:00am
echo $hours->startMonday;
```

I need to be able to change the day part dynamically with a variable, since it can be any day of the week.

```
//so something like
echo $hours->start.$day;
```

but that doesnt work

Comment: can you show the full code?

Comment: Don't use variable variablenames. Try a method, e.g. `$hours->start($day)`.

Comment: why not use this `call_user_func_array(array($hours, 'start'.$day), $args)` ?

Comment: What is `$hours->start`? An object?

Comment: check my edit. Hopefully its more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. You could edit syntax with

```
$hours = new stdClass();
$day = 'Sunday';
$hours->{'start'.$day} = 10;
$start = $hours->{'start'.$day};
var_dump($start);
```

Secnod. Better ot use getter and setter methods.

```
class Hours
    {
    private $hours = array();
    public function getStart($day)
        {
        return $this->hours[$day];
        }
    public function setStart($day, $value)
        {
        $this->hours[$day] = $value;
        }
    }
$hours = new Hours();
$day = 'Sunday';
$hours->setStart($day, 10);
$start = $hours->getStart($day);
var_dump($start);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use magic method, __get() and __set()

```
class Hours {
    private $data = array();

    public function __get($day) {
        return $this->data[$day];
    }

    public function __set($day, $val) {
        $this->data[$day] = $val;
    }
}

$h = new Hours();
echo $hours->startMonday;
```